# EF Core many-to-many join data will not save

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core

I am making a request to a cloud API to get some vendor data and I want to add or update that data into a SQL Database. There is a many-to-many relationship between Vendor and Vendor Classifications on the SQL Database (mapping is below). Unfortunately, EF Core won't save the many-to-many join data. Why not?

First, I get vendor classifications and then the vendors themselves. The calls out to the API clearly work and return the data that I expect. In the JSON response each vendor has a field named vendor_classifications which is an array of vendor classification objects. That object is simply an id and name. Here's a screenshot example of that just below.

[image]

```
        var apiVendorClassifications = await _bClient.GetVendorClassifications();
        var savedVendorClassifications = _appDbContext.VendorClassifications.ToList();
        var apiVendorClassificationsProjected = apiVendorClassifications.Select(x => new Entities.VendorClassification
        {
            Id = new Guid(x.id),
            Name = x.name
        }).ToList();
        foreach (var apiVC in apiVendorClassificationsProjected)
        {
            if (savedVendorClassifications.Find(x => x.Id == apiVC.Id) is Entities.VendorClassification found)
            {
                _appDbContext.Entry(found).CurrentValues.SetValues(apiVC);
            }
            else
                _appDbContext.Add(apiVC);
        }


        var apiVendors = await _bClient.GetVendors();
        var savedVendors = _appDbContext.Vendors.ToList();
        var apiVendorsProjected = apiVendors.Select(x => new Entities.Vendor
        {
            Id = new Guid(x.id),
            IsActive = x.is_active,
            IsVerified = x.address.verified,
            UpdatedAt = x.updated_at,
            ExternalKey = x.external_key,
            Email = x.email,
            IsDeleted = x.deleted,
            Name = x.name,
            Phone = x.phone,
            VendorClassifications = _appDbContext.VendorClassifications.Where(y => x.vendor_classifications.Select(z => new Guid(z.id)).ToList().Contains(y.Id)).ToList()
        }).ToList();
        foreach (var apiV in apiVendorsProjected)
        {
            if (savedVendors.Find(x => x.Id == apiV.Id) is Entities.Vendor found)
            {
                _appDbContext.Entry(found).CurrentValues.SetValues(apiV);
            }
            else
                _appDbContext.Add(apiV);
        }

        _appDbContext.SaveChanges();
```

In my OnModelCreating event I have configured the many-to-many mapping:

```
        // many-to-many relationship between Vendors and Vendor Classifications as we find in Prism
        modelBuilder.Entity<Vendor>().HasMany(e => e.VendorClassifications).WithMany(e => e.Vendors);
```

Comment: what u want @tnk

Comment: What does "EF Core won't save" mean? Are you getting an error? One issue might be that this line only looks at what's already in the DB, not what you just fetched from the API: `VendorClassifications = _appDbContext.VendorClassifications.Where(...`